# SQL query with multiple like operator

Tags: mysql

I need to pull records where country name is japan and the email ends with these values.

```
select * from vw_dwcontact 
where countryname = 'japan'
and email_address like '%.kr' or 
email_address like '%.kp' or
email_address like '%.it' or
email_address like '%.co' or
email_address like '%.pe' or
email_address like '%.ve' or
email_address like '%.ec' or
email_address like '%.gt' or
email_address like '%.bo' or
email_address like '%.do' or
email_address like '%.hn' or
email_address like '%.py' or
email_address like '%.sv' or
email_address like '%.br' or
email_address like '%.mx' or
email_address like '%.ar' or
email_address like '%.cl' or
email_address like '%.cn' or
email_address like '%.de' or
email_address like '%.ru' or
email_address like '%.fr' or
email_address like '%.es'
```

When I am running the above query and the result set is returning records that do not include japan? What is wrong with this query? If the where clause specifies countryname = 'japan', it should return records only with country as japan that have the above specified email address.

Please help!
Thanks.

Comment: You need to group your conditions using parentheses: `WHERE countryname='japan' AND (email_address LIKE '%.kr' OR email_address LIKE '%.kp')`